# Rspec nginx path - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, rspec

I have in my nginx

```
    location /get/rates/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
    }
```

which serves by node.js script

How to stub it in my rspec?

i have tried to use `webmock`

```
    stub_request(:any, "/get/rates").with(body: {data: {a: '1'}})
```

but it doesn't work

i have got an error

```
    Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/get/rates"
```

How to stub it in my rspec properly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) is what you're looking for.

> Library for stubbing and setting expectations on HTTP requests in
>   Ruby.

From documentation:

```
stub_request(:any, "www.example.com").
  to_return(body: "abc", status: 200,
    headers: { 'Content-Length' => 3 })

Net::HTTP.get("www.example.com", '/')    # ===> "abc"
```

Or you can just wrap the code that makes request into some class and mock this class instead of mocking the request.